# Запуск Apache в CentOS с разных конфиг файлов

Tags: centos, apache2

Сейчас apache на CentOS, запускаю через такую команду:

```
sudo systemctl start httpd.service
```

Как мне запускать Apache использую другой конфигурационный файл? Т.е. с указанием его вручную, не из стандартного расположения?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если конфиг-файл находится в другом расположении, тогда достаточно сделать симлинк

```
ln -s /путь к конфигу в нестандартном положении/apache2.conf /путь куда ложить линк/httpd.conf
```

В моем случае с Debian

```
ln -s /usr/share/apache2/apache2.conf /etc/apache2/apache2.conf
```

Comment: Мне необходим запуск разных конфигов при необходимости. Как я понимаю симлинк тут не подходит.

Comment: Значит можно сделать так: $ httpd -f /путь к конфигу/ но не знаю будет ли эта команда использовать также стандартный конфиг, скорее всего врятли...

Answer (score 1):

В /etc/sysconfig/httpd можно задать параметры запуска httpd, в т.ч. можно передать  -f /.../httpd.conf - для чтения другого конфига.

Answer (score 0):

можете «вручную» запускать программу `httpd`, предварительно остановив «штатный» экземпляр (с помощью, например, программы `service`).

примерно так:

```
$ sudo /usr/sbin/httpd -f /путь/к/конфигурационному.файлу
```

остановить этот вручную запущенный экземпляр можно примерно так:

```
$ sudo /usr/sbin/httpd -f /путь/к/конфигурационному.файлу -k stop
```